# MacBook Air M1 does not recognize external monitor via USB-C port

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb

I have the following issue. I bought a MacBook Air M1 (basic version) and I wanted to connect it to my external monitor (Samsung C34H890WJUX Curved monitor) via USB-C. MacBook battery is charging when it's connected to the monitor, but external monitor is not recognized! I'm sure my cable and external monitor works fine because it works with my old Thinkpad with Linux via USB-C and it works with MacBook Pro 2017 via USB-C, but it doesn't work with MacBook Air M1 with macOS Monterey. I read somewhere on the web that it works only with display port, but I don't want to buy any additional dongles or cables until I'm sure that it really works. Ideally I would like to make it work via USB-C.

Regards,
Piotr

Comment: Please detail which monitor you have.

Comment: I have Samsung C34H890WJUX Curved monitor, but it seems to be an issue with the MacBook Air, because it works fine with other laptops via USB-C.

Comment: It's a superwide display, so it could make a difference definitely. When you plug in the monitor - are you saying it does not appear at all in System Preferences > Displays? - What about in System Report?

Comment: It does not appear in System Preferences -> Display. I can see only built-in display there. I don't know where to find System Report. I also ordered USB-C -> display-port cable and I'll check this connection in the nearest days.

Comment: Click the Apple logo at the top-left. Click "About this Mac". Click "System Report".

Comment: Ok, but what do I need to search for in this system reports app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I received my USB-C -> Display Port cable at **it works** with my external monitor. It seems that MacBook Air M1 simply **does not work with USB-C -> USB-C cable** for connecting external displays and it just charges the battery.

Comment: Which USB-C cable do you use to connect?

Comment: I don't know exact technical details of this cable. It's non-apple regular USB-C -> USB-C cable. I'm pretty sure, this issue is not related to this cable, because it works with ThinkPad laptop (with Linux) and older MacBook Pro (Intel i5) laptop. It doesn't work with the new MacBook Air M1 laptop only.

Comment: I would suggest trying with a full thunderbolt cable just to see if that helps.

Comment: How can I verify that a specific USB-C cable is "full thunderbolt" and what does it mean? I don't want to buy more cables just to check if they work and how could you explain the fact that my current cable works correctly with MacBook Pro 2017 and Thinkpad via USB-C? If it wasn't "full thunderdolt" I suppose, It wouldn't work with these computers either.

Answer (score 1):

To summarise, I don't know the problem but I hope the added info helps people understand the issue and may be able to help us all.

It's an issue with the M1/M2 MacBooks. I got the exact same issue.
My M1 MacBook is connected to Samsung UW curved monitor.
My Monitor has USB ports for my keyboard/mouse dongle and webcam.
When my MacBook is connected, the keyboard/mouse work fine, the webcam works fine, MacBook is charging. BUT my monitor display remains black.
The occasional times it does work, it can cause the screen to jitter.

It didn't work with the Samsung-provided cable, but when I switched to a Thunderbolt 3 cable by Belkin, it worked 9 out of 10 times.

Most recently, it's been playing up again and I don't know why.
I read it's due to the frame rates not matching up, as the MacBooks now have ProMotion Technology?

Funnily, my colleague has a similar setup with a Dell monitor and he's managed to connect 3 screens with no issue.

I also didn't have an issue with an Intel MacBook.

Comment: Just FYI: My current setup with Macbook Air M1 is external (non-apple) dongle with multiple ports (HDMI, USB, USB-C, memory cards) and I'm connecting monitor via HDMI in this dongle. If a lid is closed, laptop needs to be connected to the charger (via USB-C port in this dongle). It's a pity that this setup cannot be achieved without dongles on a single cable and cheaper non-apple laptops can do that. I see they fixed this a bit by adding more ports in the recent Macbooks Pro, but I'm not gonna buy a new laptop just for that :-).