# No display on Dell USB-C monitor with M1 MacBook Pro, but charging through USB-C is ok

Tags: display, usb, charging, apple-silicon

I have a MacBook Pro 14' from 2021 with an M1 chip. I try to connect it to the Dell P2720DC monitor (service tag: F05TKF3). What I'd like to achieve is display and charging through USB-C.

- When I use a USB-C connection, there is no display on the monitor, but charging is okay. In display settings, the monitor pops up for a second and then disappears for more seconds repeatedly.
- When I use USB-C + HDMI connection, the display works (through HDMI) and charging works as well (through USB-C). In display settings, I see two monitors (this time constantly).

I tested my MacBook on a different Dell monitor with USB-C (no charging, though), and the display worked fine. The problematic monitor also has been tested with a different (non-M1) mac, and charging and display were okay, so I think it is not a thing with the cable.

I tried Dell support, and they sent me semi-related tricks with pressing the power button on the monitor and changing some of its configurations, but it didn't help. In the end, they admitted that this monitor seemed incompatible with my M1 Mac. I know there is [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/438304/macbook-air-m1-does-not-recognize-external-monitor-via-usb-c-port) thread, but it is concerned with MacBook Air, and the solution considers using DisplayPort, which is unavailable on my MacBook.

Comment: My first thought is your USB-C cable doesn't support data transfer. Have you tried other cables? Do you know what version of USB-C it is?

Comment: @AshZade this cable works fine (power+display) with other Mac (non-M1 12' MacBook), so I guess it is okay?